# Problemas para carregar o pacote Swirl

Tags: r

Consegui instalar o pacote swirl, mas quando dou o comando library(swirl), o seguinte erro aparece:

> ```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>  there is no package called ‘crayon’
> ```

Então eu tento instalar o pacote crayon e aparece:

> ```
> * installing *source* package 'crayon' ...
> ** package 'crayon' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
>   cannot open file 'C:/Users/Tams/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/crayon/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
> Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
>   it's not possible to open the conection
> ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'crayon'
> * removing 'C:/Users/TAÍS/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/crayon'
> Warning in install.packages :
>   running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\TAÍS\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\TAS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpc9eX85/downloaded_packages/crayon_1.3.4.tar.gz' had status 1
> Warning in install.packages :
>   installation of package ‘crayon’ had non-zero exit status
> ```

Como posso resolver esse problema e carregar o pacote swirl?

Comment: Como tentou instalar o pacote `crayon`? Na mensagem diz `*source* package`. Eu acabei de fazer `install.packages("crayon")` e correu bem. Também em Windows.